# Angular <mat-table>: disable sort header for specific column

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a `mat-table` with the `matSort` attribute. As I understood, this enables the sort header for all columns. Is there any possibility to disable the sort header for a single column?

With `<table mat-table>...</table>`, I can specify a `mat-sort-header` for each column, but not with `<mat-table>...</mat-table>`.

Comment: When you add `matSort` attribute in the `mat-table` who datasource was a MatTableDataSource, is created a "MatSort" that look for inside all the `*matHeaderCellDef ` with the attribute `mat-sort-header`. If you has no mat-sort-header you has no sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[disable]` attribute:

```
<th
  mat-header-cell
  *matHeaderCellDef
  [mat-sort-header]="column.name"
  [disabled]="column.name === 'actions'" // Here
  [style.width]="column.width"
>
  {{ column.label }}
</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding [disabled] attribute on mat-sort-header and giving it the column name worked for me.

`<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [disabled]="column === 'Select'">`

Comment: How is this different to the existing solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can remove `mat-sort-header` from `th` to prevent it from sorting

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
      <tr>
        <th mat-sort-header="name">row-1</th> // sortable
        <th>row-2</th> 
        <th>row-3</th>
      </tr>

      <tr *ngFor="let row of sortedTable">
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.address }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```